# Is there a DevExpress DateEdit mode where users can type numbers without slash delimiter

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

Users who are used to working with another software package would like to type just the numbers of dates, without slashes:  `0 9 1 8 2 0 1 7`. They have developed "muscle-memory" for dates and are pretty grumpy about having to enter the slashes.

This is a "heads down" data-entry scenario where they have to enter hundreds of dates, and speed is a concern. They say that they often have to enter dates from previous years, and it takes too long to navigate to the past years using the dropdown calendar.

Is there a mode setting for the DevExpress DateEdit for Winforms which allows that mode of entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to [specify a mask](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1497/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Simple-Editors/Concepts/Masks/Mask-Type-Date-time), I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks, the mask in combination with MaskType `DateTimeAdvancingCaret` gives the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Set mask property, as you need.. but you must be clear what type of date format user will enter